# WebDAV drive available offline in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, webdav, offline-files

Normal mapped network drives have the handy option "Always available offline" in Win 10 which is great because files can be available even when the network is gone.

Unfortunately I miss this option for network drives that are mapped via WebDAV.

Is there any way to get the same behavior for WebDAV network drives?